# How to animate BoxView position?

Tags: animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to have two buttons side by side, and a BoxView, which will stand under the button which is pressed, therefore it must be able to slide from under one button, to another. I tried looking for that but cannot find anything related to Xamarin Forms position animation. How can I do that?
Any resources or advices on doing what I'm trying to do will be welcomed, thanks.

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-animations-with-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LayoutTo(position, duration, easing)` method like:

```
yourBoxView.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(x,y,width,height),500,Easing.Linear)
```

Comment: could you elaborate? what is this `Rectangle`?

Comment: `Rectangle`: Specifies a rectangle area in the screen. i.e: `new Rectangle(1,2,3,4)` => starting xPosition =1 , starting yPosition=2, `Width`=3, `Height`=4. In your button click action you will call `LayoutTo` method.

You should also check [Easing][1] class for specifying animation style.


  [1]: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Easing/